# 403 forbidden response when attempting to use Tumblr images after jQuery call

Tags: ajax, jquery, tumblr, http-status-code-403

so I am trying to build a tumblr site that will be able to auto paginate, integrate with colorbox and load tagged elements by a jQuery.ajax and load them to the Dom.

I'm getting the jsonp response, and I am parsing it just fine, and then when I append the  I get a console log that tells me that this file is forbidden. I am thinking I need to pass my api key with the request for the image but I don't know how to do this.

My code is below.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ryansimmonsiscool.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=myApikey&limit=6',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    var posts = results.response.posts;
    $.each(posts, function(i, posts) {
      //console.log(this.photos);

      var photos = this.photos;

      $.each(photos, function(i, photos) {
        console.log(this.alt_sizes[3].url);
        var thumb = '<img src=' + this.alt_sizes[3].url + '/>';
        $('#contSlug').append(thumb);
        console.log(this.original_size.url);
        var fullres = '<img src=' + this.original_size.url + '/>';
        $('#contSlug').append(fullres);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

EDIT: I've also tried defining my $.ajaxSetup to include my api_key so that when the image is appended and client asks the server for the data it is retrieved using the api_key in the get method (code below) but I am still getting a 403 and broken links.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  data: {
    api_key:'example-api-key'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the request type and the data in the request as a variable `type` (set to 'get' or 'post' as needed). Then make a `data` object and set the request variables in that object. This will be passed to the server using the method specified in `type`.

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
data: {
        api_key:myAPIKeyGoesHere,
        limit:6
},
url:'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ryansimmonsiscool.tumblr.com/posts/photo',
cache: false,
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
    console.log(results);
    var posts = results.response.posts;
    $.each(posts, function (i, posts){

        //console.log(this.photos);

        var photos = this.photos;

        $.each(photos, function (i, photos) {
            console.log(this.alt_sizes[3].url)
            var thumb = "<img src="+this.alt_sizes[3].url+"/>";
            $("#contSlug").append(thumb);
            console.log(this.original_size.url)
            var fullres = "<img src="+this.original_size.url+"/>";
            $("#contSlug").append(fullres);
            })
        })
}
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's better syntax granted, but I still have the problem that when I append the DOM and the client asks for the actual image data via the img url it returns a 403 to the console. 
I am going to try to define the ajax defaults with an api_key.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but doesn't `this` inside `$.each` refer to the jQuery created object and not the object with the `alt_size[3]` prop?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue... Not sure if the same problem, but in my case  the ending slash in the image tag is what was throwing it off, so change the above like so:

`var fullres = "<img src="+this.original_size.url+">";`

I was using underscore.js templates to do something similar, which ended working like this:

`<img src=<%= post.photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url %>>`

Aside from that our code is the same using ajax etc..